# Dropdown menu in MRTK3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Is it possible to make the Unity3D dropdown menu work in combination with the MRTK3 so that is interactable on the HL2? If so, how? In MRTK2 it was possible by attaching a script to the dropdown object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to interact with Unity’s built-in elements using MRTK 3. To do this, you need to add a new component called the **Tracked Device Graphic Raycaster** to the canvas. This component lets you use 3D tracked devices to highlight and select UI elements in that canvas. Please note that the **Render Mode** in Canvas should be set to **World Space**. For more details, you can refer to https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@2.0/manual/ui-setup.html.

This new component is contained from Unity XR Interactable Toolkit(XRI), and most interaction and input features in MRTK 3 are simply inherited from XRI. If you are new to XRI, I recommend you starting with Unity’s [XRI architecture documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@2.0/manual/architecture.html). All XRI documentation also applies to MRTK 3.

Here are some links that will help you understand the interactions in MRTK 3 :

[Migration guide from MRTK2 to MRTK3 - MRTK3 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/architecture/mrtk-v2-to-v3)

[Interactor architecture - MRTK3 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/architecture/interactors)

[Interactables - MRTK3 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-overview/architecture/interactables)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very useful! As a side note for anyone stumbling across this in the future, in particular the first link regarding UI interaction setup was very helpful. I also had to replace/remove the `InputSystemUIInputModule` from the `Eventsystem` as this was preventing proper behavior.

Comment: A quick follow up question: Applying these methods allows far interaction for me. How can this be transferred to work for near interaction as well?

Comment: Firstly, to add near interactivity, ensure  that the desired GameObject has a Collider component (ex: Box Collider).
However, the **TrackedDeviceGraphicRaycaster** only tracks graphics. So, you need to add another component called the **TrackedDevicePhysicsRaycaster**, which detects UI elements with physics colliders attached to their gameObjects in the canvas.

Comment: I tried to make it work based on your tips, but it doesn't seem to be enough. Adding the `TrackedDevicePhysicsRaycaster` allows far interaction (even without the `TrackedDeviceGraphicRaycaster`. I added a box collider to the dropdown. I mean 3D buttons use the `UGUIInputAdapter` component to transfer the UI events I think. However, this component can't be added on top of a dropdown